# Kmer counting with Perl

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

I'm very new to Perl and to scripting, but I need a code for a research of mine. I'm trying to calculate the frequency of 11-mers in DNA sequences stored in a multiFASTA file. By merging together some scripts I found, I wrote this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$k = 11;  @bases = ('A','C','G','T');
@words = @bases; open FILE1, ">kmers.txt" or die $!;
for $i (1..$k-1)  {
   undef @newwords;
   foreach $w (@words)
   {
       foreach $b (@bases)
       {
          push (@newwords,$w.$b);
       }
   }
   undef @words;
   @words = @newwords;  
}
foreach $w (@words) {  
   print FILE1 "$w \n"; 
} 
close FILE1;   
my $input=$ARGV[0]; 
my $output=$ARGV[1];
open(IN,"<$input") || die ("Error opening $input $!"); 
open OUT, ">$output" or die $|; my $line = <IN>;  
print OUT $line; 
while ($line = <IN>) { 
   chomp $line; 
   if ($line=~m/^>/) { 
      print OUT  "\n",$line,"\n"; 
   } else { 
      print OUT $line; 
   } 
} 
print OUT "\n";

chomp $seq; chomp $k;
#obtain all distinct kmers open FILE2, ">out.txt" or die $!;

for $line (@lines) { 
   if ($line=~m/^>/) { next; } 
}
foreach($i=1; length($line) >= $k; $i++)    {   
   $line =~ m/(^.{$k})/;  
   $w{$1}{cnt}++;
   push @{$w{$1}{pos}}, $i;  
   $line= substr($seq, 1, length($line)-1);
   foreach $line (keys %kmers)    {
      print FILE2 "$kmers\n";
   }
   close FILE2; 
   close OUT;    
}
```

Basically, it reads the file, puts all sequence lines in one line in a separate file, writes down all the 11mers and creates an "out.txt" file in which I'd like him to store sequence headers with 11-mer frequences. Here's the hard part (for me): how do I tell the script to write the sequence header along with the 11mer frequencies for each sequence?

Comment: What does this header look like? Is it additional data, or is it just a first line with headings? Where does the header come from? Also, please take a look at http://perl-begin.org/tutorials/modern-perl/ and start using `strict` and `warnings` as they will make your life easier.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please remember that we may not be bioinformatics experts. Even if some of us are, sample input and output files would make it easier to understand what your problem is and address it effectively.

Comment: Have a look at [BioPerl](http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/Main_Page).

Comment: you could also ask biostars: http://www.biostars.org/

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your insights. :)
My files usually look like this:

>header
line

I'd like my script to do the following:
1) compile a list of all possible kmers of length k using the 4 bases (A, C, G, T) (done);
2) open the data file, store somewhere the header and sift through the sequence to look for the kmers created;
3) count occurences of each kmer and store them;
4) calculate H' from the kmer frequencies;
5) open an output file containing sequence header and respective H';
6) repeat 2-5 for each sequence.

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering with the code, I produced this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $in_file = $ARGV[0];
my $out_tvir = $ARGV[1];
my $k = $ARGV[2];
my %seq_hash; # key = seq_name, value = seq;
{
# redefine the record separator
local $/ = ">";
open IN, "<$in_file";
my $in_line = <IN>; # toss the first record
while ( $in_line = <IN> ) {
    chomp $in_line; # remove the ">" character in the end 
    my ( $seq_name, $seq ) = split( /\n/, $in_line, 2 );
    $seq =~ tr/ \t\n\r//d;    # Remove whitespace
    $seq_hash{$seq_name} = uc $seq;
}
close IN;
}

open OUT, ">$out_file";
open OUT2, ">$out_tvir";
foreach my $seq_name ( sort keys %seq_hash ) {
chomp $k;
%kmers = ();
while (length($seq_hash{$seq_name}) >= $k)
    {
    $seq_hash{$seq_name}=~ m/(^.{$k})/;
    $kmers{$1}++;
    $seq_hash{$seq_name}= substr($seq_hash{$seq_name}, 1,         length($seq_hash{$seq_name})-1);
    }
    $num_kmers = keys %kmers;
$px=();
$logpx=();
my $H=();
foreach $str (keys %kmers)
{
    my $px=$kmers{$str}/$num_kmers;
    $logpx=log($px);
    $H -= $px * log($px);
    if ($H <= 18) {print OUT2 ">$seq_name\t$H\n";}
}
}
close OUT;
```

...which kind of works, if I omit the last "if ($H..." part and just let the script do the job by listing all the H values associated with each sequence. I can't figure out why, though.

Answer (score 0):

user2029917, you had some problems with undeclared variables, which would have prevented the script from running with `use strict;` turned on; I made some modifications and cleaned it up a bit.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $in_file = $ARGV[0];
my $out_tvir = $ARGV[1];
my $k = $ARGV[2];

my %seq_hash; # key = seq_name, value = seq;
{
    # redefine the record separator
    local $/ = ">";
    open IN, "<", $in_file or die "Can't open ${in_file}: $!";
    my $in_line = <IN>; # toss the first record
    while ( $in_line = <IN> ) {
        chomp $in_line; # remove the ">" character in the end 
        my ( $seq_name, $seq ) = split( /\n/, $in_line, 2 );
        $seq =~ tr/\t\n\r//d;    # Remove whitespace
        $seq_hash{$seq_name} = uc $seq;
    }
    close IN;
}

open OUT, ">", $out_tvir or die "Can't open ${out_tvir}: $!";
foreach my $seq_name ( sort keys %seq_hash ) {
    chomp $k;
    my %kmers;
    while (length($seq_hash{$seq_name}) >= $k) {
        $seq_hash{$seq_name}=~ m/(^.{$k})/;
        $kmers{$1}++;
        $seq_hash{$seq_name}= substr($seq_hash{$seq_name}, 1, length($seq_hash{$seq_name})-1);
    }
    my $num_kmers = keys %kmers;
    my $px;
    my $logpx;
    my $H;
    foreach my $str (keys %kmers) {
        my $px=$kmers{$str}/$num_kmers;
        $logpx=log($px);
        $H -= $px * log($px);
        if ($H <= 18) {print OUT ">$seq_name\t$H\n";}
    }
}

close OUT;

exit;
```

It should run, now, but I'm not sure if this script produces the output you're after.  For example, for a given k-mer, it will print the H' value for every FASTA entry in which it appears (which will always be the same value, regardless of FASTA entry, since it's being calculated with the total occurrence and total number of k-mers).  At present, it doesn't print WHICH k-mer is being referred to.  That's something that could be fixed by changing the last bit to `print OUT ">$seq_name\t$str\t$H\n";`, but I'm not sure if that's the behavior you're after.  We might be able to be of more help if you could provide some more detail about the output you need.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create an intermediate file to force each sequence to be a single line, your loop counting 11mers can be much simpler, and I don't see why you're creating kmers.txt with all possible 11mers because you don't use it.  Plus, there are a number of syntactic errors and unused variables.  And you don't need that 3rd argument to substr.  The default goes to the end if you leave it off.

Aside from those issues, note there are 4^11 possible 11mers that can exist, which is nearly 4.2M possibilities. Your deflines are going to be enormous (depending on the length of sequences you're analyzing).  I'd guess that a typical gene would be upwards of a thousand 11mers, unless you're analyzing repeat sequences.  You might consider only including an arbitrary number of the most abundant 11mers in your deflines (unless you plan on processing the output programmatically - but even then, having lines that long can be problematic).

Your submitted answer has some extra intent that is not in your question, but setting that aside for now, here is how I would write the script to include the top 5 11mer frequencies in your sequences (arbitrarily selecting between any ties for 5th place).  I will not address the proper coding practice issues that others have advised you on - but you should heed those suggestions.

```
my $input=$ARGV[0]; 
my $output=$ARGV[1];

my $defline = '';
my $seq = '';
my $topkmers = '';

open(INPUT,$input);
open(OUTPUT,">$output");
select(OUTPUT);

while(<INPUT>)
  {
    chomp;
    if(/^>/)
      {
        if($seq ne '')
          {
            $topkmers = getTopKMers($seq,11,5);
            print("$defline $topkmers\n$seq\n");
          }
        $defline = $_;
        $seq = '';
      }
    else
      {$seq .= $_}
  }
#Take care of the last record
if($seq ne '')
  {
    $topkmers = getKMers($seq);
    print("$defline $topkmers\n$seq\n");
  }

close(INPUT);
close(OUTPUT);

sub getTopKMers
  {
    my $seq = uc($_[0]);
    my $size = $_[1];
    my $top = $_[2] - 1;   #Submit a 0 to get all kmers
    my $hash = {};

    #Create the abundance hash
    for(my $p = 0;$p < (length($seq) - $size);$p++)
      {push(@{$hash->{substr($seq,$p,$size)}},$p}

    #Sort by abundance
    my @sorted = sort {scalar(@{$hash->{$b}}) <=> scalar(@{$hash->{$a}})} keys(%$hash);

    #Get the top few most abundant kmers
    my @toplist = $top > -1 ? @sorted[0..$top] : @sorted;

    #Creates a string like "ATGCATGCCAA[20]=1,2,... CGTAGCTCTAG[18]=6,23,..."
    my $str = join(' ',
                   map {
                        "$_\[" .
                        scalar(@{$hash->{$_}}}) .
                        "]=" .
                        join(',',@{$hash->{$_}})
                       } @toplist);

    return($str);
  }
```

This could eliminate the sort and merge a few steps to make it more efficient, but there's something to be said for easier to read code.

NOTE: I have not run this code, so please excuse any errors I overlooked.